# Failed to read descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While creating Maven project in eclipse throws

> Failed to read descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

I have done these things

- delete maven-resources-plugin alone from .m2 folder and then create a maven project
- delete whole .m2 folder and then create a maven project
- mvn -U clean install

but nothing worked

Comment: Are you sure whether you've set up proper proxy in settings.xml

Comment: @PratikAmbani yes , proxy settings are proper in maven/conf/settings.xml , but i could not see settings.xml in .m2 folder .

Comment: Nooo, you'll find settings.xml inside conf directory of your maven installation directory.

Comment: @PratikAmbani yes , checked the same .I didnt changed anything in default proxy settings . I am using the network which is working fine for others .

Comment: mvn -U dependency:resolve try this

Comment: worked fine once i replaced the .m2 folder from other maven working laptop

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. Shall I post this as an answer?

Comment: yeah , but this is not the optimal solution , i just copied the working .m2 folder from other laptop . i didn't tried ur solution mvn -U dependency:resolve as well . Up to U .